# Astyle like library for PHP and Javascript

Tags: c++, code-formatting, astyle

[Astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) is excellent code formatter for Java C# C++ eta al but it does not format PHP nor Javascrpt. Is there any free opensource code formatter for PHP and Javascript? Google is not very helpful for this case.

NB: I need a C/C++ library as that is a language I'm programming with.

Comment: I continue to be stunned by people that will close a recommendation question, without explaining to the OP that they might be able formulate such a question, and get decent answers at another StackExchange site, SoftwareRecommendations.  See http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: That is our "new world order" I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going for PHP Class. I plan to run with PHP to produce desirable results
The code is found [here](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier/download)